# Spring boot with oAuth2 OauthException: “You must provide a client_id”

Tags: spring-boot, instagram, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

In my project I am trying to authenticate user with instagram.
This project is running on **spring-boot** with *spring-security-oauth2*.
On authentication phase I recieve from instagram `code`, which is sent to instagram to retrieve `access_token`. Instead of `access_token` I recieve bad request response with message: "You must provide a client_id".

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index**", "/login/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(instagram(), "/login"), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("instagram")
ClientResources instagram() {
    return new ClientResources();
}

private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path) {

    };
    OAuth2RestTemplate filterTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(filterTemplate);
    filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                                                              client.getClient().getClientId()));
    return filter;
}
```

**application.properties**

```
instagram.client.clientId=df5cc67d71e04b1b9a89ca9e1572a801
instagram.client.clientSecret=8da04f4072a54579ae4e334d5e865fa4
instagram.client.accessTokenUri=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
instagram.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
instagram.client.scope=basic, likes, comments, relationships
instagram.resource.userInfoUri=https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self
```

[Here](https://github.com/Solorad/morestat.git) is that project on github. Project for education purposes, so here are openned clientId and clientSecret.
Thanks for any advice how to solve that annoying exception in advance

Answer (score -1):

In OAuth2 there are multiple flows in which we can perform authtentication grants. The flow that you chose is Authorization Code flow.

In Authrorization Code flow the authorization server returns an authorization code to the user agent (browser). Browser then posts that code back to the Resource Server (Api code running on the server). Then the server exchanges that code along with client id and client secret for an access_token.

The client Id and secret are confidential hence Implicit flow is recommended when you are using OAuth2 in a Javascript based applications. In this flow the authrorization server responds with access_token instead of a Authorization code.

Please let me know if this is helpful or you have any other questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: I dont see here any useful information. Explicit code flow was used and it was not working.

Comment: I don't see a call for the access_token with client_id, client_secret and the access code

Comment: because spring-oauth is doing all that for me. Problem is on the  last step of authentication.  
I see, you don't understand my question, and your answer is just copy-paste from some oauth documentation.

Comment: K. I misunderstood your question. I didn't copy my answer, it was based on the error message “You must provide a client_id". I will look into your github solution to see if can help. Thank you.